# Plotting a time series of positions on a map

Tags: python, geopandas

Is there a good way of displaying a series of timestamps on a map, in a way that highlights the temporal aspect, as the points are in order of appearance?
Basically I am trying to track an object throughout the city. I have the respective coordinates of the current point and the point, where the object was previously spotted, and the respective timestamps along with some other related features.

Ideally in python, but I can see myself picking up a more cartography specific tool for it.

What I have tried: I created n (tested with 3 and 5) points in addition to current and previous position and plotted a heatmap with those points, but that doesn't really capture the "Ordered", time-series, aspect of it all.

Comment: You may want to take  a look at [movingpandas](https://github.com/anitagraser/movingpandas) package.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it with the movingpandas package, as Kadir suggested:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import movingpandas as mpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import contextily as ctx
import geoplot

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (25, 25), dpi = 200)

df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/csv").set_index('snapshot_timestamp')
    
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry = gpd.points_from_xy(df['lng'], df['lat']), crs = 'EPSG:4326')

traj = mpd.Trajectory(gdf, 1)

traj.plot(ax = ax)
ctx.add_basemap(ax, crs = 'EPSG:4326')

plt.show()
```